# How to remove variable name from the side of data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I am answering this question for an assignment:

**What is the variance in total sleep for carnivores and those whose conservation status is
lc?**

I have the right answer but the code is including the name: `sleep_total`
to the left of my data frame and I am having trouble removing it.

These are the 2 codes I've tried so far that each gave the same output:

```
  Q1 <- msleep %>%
  filter(vore == "carni" & conservation == "lc") %>%
  var(sleep_total) %>% 
  round(2) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  setNames("var")

Q1

Q1 <- msleep %>%
  filter(vore == "carni" & conservation == "lc") %>%
  select(sleep_total) %>%
  var() %>% 
  round(2) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  setNames("var")

Q1
```

What I'm expecting is everything I have in the output already, I just need it to not show `sleep_total` in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your code *should* be producing an error.

```r
mtcars %>%
  filter(cyl == 4) %>%
  var(disp)
# Error in is.data.frame(y) : object 'disp' not found
```

The fact that it is not erring for you suggests you have an object in your working environment named `sleep_total` (and is likely to be not correct, since it will not be `filter`ed as you expect).

If we `select` it first as in your second code block, we get a better idea of what's going on:

```r
res <- mtcars %>%
  filter(cyl == 4) %>%
  select(disp) %>%
  var() %>%
  round(2) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  setNames("var")
res
#         var
# disp 722.08
```

Assuming you want it to print as a regular frame, we need to remove the *row names* of the frame, added by `var` when it created the matrix.

```r
dimnames(res)
# [[1]]
# [1] "disp"
# [[2]]
# [1] "var"
rownames(res) <- NULL
res
#      var
# 1 722.08
```

Regardless, *it's just a name*, you still have the value you need.

---

An alternative is to summarize it and define your name *then*, introducing no row names.

```r
mtcars %>%
  filter(cyl == 4) %>%
  summarize(var = var(disp))
#        var
# 1 722.0825
```

Much simpler.